# lftp cannot connecto to IIS

Tags: iis, ftp

I can not connect to IIS using lftp as you can see here:

```
<--- 200 Language is now English, UTF-8 encoding.
---> OPTS UTF8 ON
<--- 200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
---> HOST x.x.x.x
<--- 504 Server cannot accept argument.
---> USER bla
<--- 331 Password required for hgtrf.
---> PASS blabla
<--- 230 User logged in.
---> PWD
<--- 257 "/" is current directory.
---> PBSZ 0
<--- 200 PBSZ command successful.
---> PROT P
<--- 534 Policy denies SSL.
---> PASV
<--- 227 Entering Passive Mode (x.x.x.x,194,118).
---- Connecting data socket to (x.x.x.x) port 49782
**** Socket error (Connection refused) - reconnecting
---> LIST
---> ABOR
---- Closing aborted data socket
---- Closing control socket
```

I could connect, list, retrieve and send files using standard ftp command. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure you have disabled ssl:

```
lftp -d -u user,password -e "set ftp:ssl-allow no" server-address
```

Comment: I had an issue logging in with lftp to a PureFTPd server. The client machine was Windows 7 (lftp running in Cygwin). I could not even do an `ls', but the answer helped!